# How to tell from a JSON array or a JSON?

Tags: json

I have a JSON file which is from a server but don't know what the difference from a string or a list or a array.

What I am trying to do is using the server html such as http://servername:5018/hoteldata and I don't know how to tell from an array or list or string, I want to call it from that as it is a JSON file and call it on HTML

```
        [
  {
    "firstname": "Bill", 
    "lastname": "Richson", 
    "numberofguest": "1"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Jane", 
    "lastname": "Freda", 
    "numberofguest": "3"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Mark", 
    "lastname": "Harrison", 
    "numberofguest": "7"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Chris", 
    "lastname": "Asher", 
    "numberofguest": "4"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Ruth", 
    "lastname": "King", 
    "numberofguest": "2"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Andy", 
    "lastname": "Webb", 
    "numberofguest": "5"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Mary ", 
    "lastname": "Gardner", 
    "numberofguest": "2"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Mark", 
    "lastname": "Harrison", 
    "numberofguest": "7"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Anna ", 
    "lastname": "Mitchell", 
    "numberofguest": "1"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Karl", 
    "lastname": "Robertson", 
    "numberofguest": "3"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Liam", 
    "lastname": "Barnard", 
    "numberofguest": "2"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Tommy", 
    "lastname": "McCree", 
    "numberofguest": "4"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Peter", 
    "lastname": "Root", 
    "numberofguest": "6"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Test", 
    "lastname": "Guest", 
    "numberofguest": "1"
  }
]
```

Comment: Strings have quotes around them, arrays have brackets, objects have curly brackets. Arrays are sometimes called lists. Your example is an array of objects. Each object has 3 properties firstname, lastname and hotel_id, and each of these properties is a string value. Additionally in your example the values don't seem to match property names.

Comment: Re-updated the example, Sorry i ment to change the data in the coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse the incoming JSON, then it's easy to spot if it's an array or not with [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

```js
var json =  `[
  {
    "firstname": "Richson", 
    "hotel_id": "Bill", 
    "lastname": "1"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Freda", 
    "hotel_id": "Jane", 
    "lastname": "3"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Harrison", 
    "hotel_id": "Mark", 
    "lastname": "7"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Asher", 
    "hotel_id": "Chris", 
    "lastname": "4"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "King", 
    "hotel_id": "Ruth", 
    "lastname": "2"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Webb", 
    "hotel_id": "Andy", 
    "lastname": "5"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Gardner", 
    "hotel_id": "Mary ", 
    "lastname": "2"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Harrison", 
    "hotel_id": "Mark", 
    "lastname": "7"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Mitchell", 
    "hotel_id": "Anna ", 
    "lastname": "1"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Robertson", 
    "hotel_id": "Karl", 
    "lastname": "3"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Barnard", 
    "hotel_id": "Liam", 
    "lastname": "2"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "McCree", 
    "hotel_id": "Tommy", 
    "lastname": "4"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Root", 
    "hotel_id": "Peter", 
    "lastname": "6"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Guest", 
    "hotel_id": "Test", 
    "lastname": "1"
  }
]`;

var parsedJson = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(Array.isArray(parsedJson))
```

Answer (score 0):

The individual components within the {}-brackets stand for a name and a value. "firstname" would be the name of the value and "Richson" is the value. That would be a string. The entirety within the {}-brackets is a JSON-object. The entirety within the []-brackets is a JSON-array.

Check out this link for more information on JSON-syntax: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp